# How do I loop over a hash of hashes in perl and access the data contained?

Tags: perl

I have a list

```
my %SERVICES = (
              name=>
              {
                 description => 'Item 1',
                 service_codes => [ 'item1' ],
              },
              name2=>
              {
                 description => 'Item 2',
                 service_codes => [ 'item2' ],
              },
            );
```

what I need to do is reference the description and print it to a variable called $service_name so when referenced the text will read Item 1 or Item 2.

I am VERY new at perl and am trying to learn this on my own the best as I can. Any help would be appreciated, please use small words. :)

Comment: That's a hash, not a list.

Comment: I'm having problems understanding what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough, try looping over the data structure

```
while ( my ($k, $data) = each %SERVICES ) {
  my $service_name = $data->{description};
  say $service_name;
}
```

Comment: perl5 doesn't have the say() function available by default. May want to throw in `use feature 'say';`, or just use `print`

Comment: Thank you, this should get me heading in the correct direction. I'll keep you updated!

Answer (score 0):

Program:

```
foreach my $id (keys %SERVICES)
{
  my $des = $SERVICES{$id}{'description'};
  print "$des\n";
}
```